# How to invoke controller setter method in trigger beforeInsert()?

Tags: apex, visualforce, before-trigger, setter

That is my VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="LeadDuplicateController" tabStyle="Lead"> 
  <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Lead Information">
            <apex:outputText value="{!plainHTML}" escape="false" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

AND That is the controller class to the VF page:

```
public with sharing class LeadDuplicateController {

    Lead objLead;

    public String plainHTML { get; set; }

    public LeadDuplicateController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        objLead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
    }
}
```

How to invoke the setter method of `plainHTML` in `beforeInsert()` method?

The issue I strive to solve is that `beforeInsert()` method is in another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if a trigger handler *could* call a Visualforce page's controller (well, it can, but only if you go through contortions to do so), it shouldn't. A trigger executes in many different contexts and should never depend on, or change behavior in, the presence of a user-interface session.

This objective is a good indicator that you need to refactor your code. If you have business logic embedded in your trigger handler that needs to play a role in the Visualforce page controller, you should consider factoring that code into a separate service class that's independent of the context in which it's called - that is, it just applies the business logic.

Then, both your trigger handler and your Visualforce page controller can call that logic and consume the results as required.